# how to change root element of api output

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, sitemap

I have created an api that gives the output in form of xml. It is used to give sitemap for the website. It just includes the following code

```
public class SitemapApiController : ApiController
{
    public urlset GetSitemap()
    {
        // code for data access etc
        return urlsetObj;
    }
}
```

the urlset class is very simple

```
[XmlRoot("urlset")]
public class urlset: List<url>
{
}
```

the url class is as follows

```
public class url
{

    public string loc { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastmod { get; set; }        
    public double priority { get; set; }
}
```

Now my problem is that output is coming as

```
<arrayofurls>
         <url>.....
```

while i want it to be

```
<urlset>
     <url>....
```

I have read the similar posts for this, but to no relief. As stated in [Modify the xml array element name in serialized ASP.NET WebAPI object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599455/modify-the-xml-array-element-name-in-serialized-asp-net-webapi-object) post, if i use

```
[XmlArray("urlset")]
```

atribute over api controller, then it gives error that attribute "XmlArray" is not valid in this declaration type. Pls help me so that i can return valid sitemap from the api. 
**Edit**

The output according to this is still a bit different. Now it shows

```
<urlset>
    <url>
        <url>
            <loc>
        <url>........
```

There is an extra needless url attribute as parent of all the url attributes.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution to this?

Comment: @ShaiCohen yes. I am still looking.

Comment: I updated my answer yesterday. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **UPDATED**

It took a little bit of work, but I believe I found what you are looking for.

A WebApi project should serialize XML using the namespace `System.Runtime.Serialization`, not the namespace `System.Xml.Serialization`.

Using this new serialization method, it becomes extremely simple to output the results exactly as you want.

The api controller `GET` method:

```
public urlset Get()
{
    return new urlset
    {
        new url { loc = "1" },
        new url { loc = "2" },
        new url { loc = "3" }
    };
}
```

The `urlset` class:

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name ="urlset", Namespace ="")]
public class urlset:List<url>
{
}
```

The `url` class:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class url
{
    [DataMember]
    public string loc { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime lastmod { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double priority { get; set; }
}
```

The output:

```
<urlset xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <url>
        <lastmod>2016-10-19T08:07:28.6867397-07:00</lastmod>
        <loc>1</loc>
        <priority>0</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <lastmod>2016-10-15T08:07:28.6867397-07:00</lastmod>
        <loc>2</loc>
        <priority>0</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <lastmod>2016-09-20T08:07:28.6867397-07:00</lastmod>
        <loc>3</loc>
        <priority>0</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

I realize the example you give in your question does not have the `xmlns` attribute in the root node. However, it seems there is no "easy" way to remove that.

Here are the resources I used to arrive at this solution:

[**StackOverflow:** How to serialize xml into desired format in asp.net web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739528/how-to-serialize-xml-into-desired-format-in-asp-net-web-api)

[**MSDN:** Collection Types in Data Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx)

Comment: this is giving the same error "the xmlarray is not valid on this declaration type".

Comment: I apologize. I sent that out too quickly. Fixing the answer now.

Comment: Hi. the output is still a bit different from what i need. Pls check the edit which i made in the question.

Comment: Thanks sir. I am overwhelmed seeing that even after so many days, you tried so hard. Another thing i want to add is that i didn't want to get rid of "xmlns" attribute. I just didn't write it for the purpose of simplicity.

Comment: Great! Glad we finally found the solution. Yes, it was a challenge, but well worth it:)